# Current in Series combination

Tags: current

I am confused as to why current in series combination of resistors remains the same?I get that it is getting one path to flow but shouldnot the current decrease when it passes through resistor 1 since its offering opposition to flow of charges and ultimately less current(assuming that speed of charge flow has decreased because it has lost energy) reaching resistor 2 ?Even if the speed doesn't effect current directly ,the time would be less right?

I think if *10 charges per* *second* were to pass through resistor 1 shouldn't the current change to *10 charges per 2 second* (Since I assume charges will pass through no matter the resistance offered by resistor but will take longer time and thereby decreasing current?)when it leaves resistor 1?

Comment: You are right, if the "force" causing this motion of electrons is the same for both series resistors. Is it the same for both? (Potential difference) think, think ...

Answer (score 1):

Given that charge is basically a flow of electrons, where would you suggest that the missing electrons might have gone if you count the electrons leaving the second resistor and compare that with the number of electrons entering the first resistor?

Water passing through a pipe then passing through a narrower pipe has the same flow rate before, through and after. Water doesn't disappear so why should electrons.

Comment: You are moving the goalposts of your question. This is a Q and A site and not a protracted learning experience or talking shop type forum. You ask a question and somebody provides an answer. Bear that in mind. Energy will be lost but the flow will remain the same. If you need the physics there is a physics side to stack exchange.